# VBA Access Pivot Table Coding

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, pivot-table, invalid-argument

I am having trouble getting past this one error when creating my Pivot Tables. It keeps saying there is an "Invalid Procedure Call or Argument" on

```
Sub AlternateRowColors()

Dim lastAddress As String

Dim myRange As Range, xlApp As Object, xlBook As Object, xlSheet As Object, xlObj As Object, xlPC As Object, xlPT As Object, xlPI As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("L:\WF Reporting\Superdash\Superdash_Reporting.xlsx")

Set xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets(4)

xlApp.Visible = True


For Each Sheet In xlBook.Sheets  
  lastAddress = Sheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address
Sheet.Activate
  Set xlLo = Sheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A1:" & lastAddress), , xlYes)
  xlLo.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium16"  


Next Sheet

    Set xlPC = xlBook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "tbl_Superdash_Bot_Rpt", xlPivotTableVersion15) 
Set xlObj = xlBook.Sheets.Add(xlSheet)
Set xlPT = xlPC.CreatePivotTable(xlLo.Range("A3"), "Superdash_Bot_pivot") 
xlObj.Name = "Summary"

With xlPT
    .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    .InGridDropZones = True
    .DisplayErrorString = True
    .ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True

 With .PivotFields("Bot_Skill_Name")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
 End With


 With .PivotFields("Human_Skill_Name")   
        .Orientation = xlPageField
 End With

End With

xlBook.Save  
xlBook.Close 
xlApp.Quit   

End Sub
```

I am getting an error on the

```
Set xlPT = xlPC.CreatePivotTable(xlLo.Range("A3"), "Superdash_Bot_pivot")'
```

line. It is saying that there is an

> Invalid Call or Argument

. It seems to me that all of these are previously defined. What am I missing?

Comment: Late-Bound `Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`doesn't know the enums (e.g. [xlPivotTableVersion15](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlpivottableversionlist-enumeration-excel) = 5).-> non declared var, value is wrong. You have to use the integer value or create your own enum or const. This won't happen with `Option Explicit`!

Comment: @ComputerVersteher: Total agree with `Option Explicit`. However, the VBA compiler does know the enum even when using late binding as long as the reference is part of the project - which is alwasy true for the Excel library. However, `xlPivotTableVersion15` is valid (and defined) starting with Excel 2013, so if you are on 2010 (or earlier), it is unknown.

Comment: @FunThomas: No, the Excel Lib is not a standard reference of ms access, which executes the code if tags are correct!

Comment: oh, you're right. Didn't saw that tag. Anyhow, that doesn't solve the problem, there is something else wrong

Comment: You too, `Dim myRange As Range` needs the reference! So it is there. I have no proper sheet to test the code, sorry.

Comment: But the Dim myRange As Range worked in my loop in the above part of the code when I added the highlight styling. How else do I need to reference it?

Comment: I do not see an Dim xlLo.  Has the Set gone out of scope? Option Explicit?